# Calculate and display the final value in Textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am very new to c# , and i am trying to do a mathematical calculation using tow or more fields in my win form application , and i am trying to show the result in a text box when the link table is clicked , although his programme is not showing any error in visual studio , i am not getting the updated value in my textbox , (that is no changes happening when i click the link label) , kindly go through my below programme and guide me where i am wrong:

```
private void TSCalc_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(materialTypeComboBox.Text == "ABC" && unitComboBox.Text == "XYZ")
                {
                    float a = float.Parse(frontWtTextBox.Text);
                    float b = float.Parse(backWtTextBox.Text);
                    float c = (a / b) / 2;
                    float d = float.Parse(cFComboBox.Text);
                    float g = (c * d);
                    decimal f = (decimal)Math.Sqrt(g);
                    tSTextBox.Text = Decimal.Round(f, 2).ToString("0.00");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Saving Failed:" + ex.Message.ToString(), "Save",
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you how to debug a code and see the change of variable values after every line of code?

Comment: i tried but i am not understanding , i have further simplified my code , could you please help me now?`tSTextBox.Text = decimal.Round((decimal)Math.Sqrt(float.Parse(frontWtTextBox.Text) / float.Parse(backWtTextBox.Text) / 2 * float.Parse(cFComboBox.Text)), 2).ToString("0.00");`

Comment: Please learn how to [Debug a code in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019), debugging is the most important thing a programmer has to have grip on.
Or you can search over youtube to find a basic tutorial. Debugging skills will make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you so much ..now i got to know where was i wrong..

Comment: I would recommend you to add an else condition and show result at the MessageBox or console, because if it didn't get into the if condition, it will do nothing and without exception...

Comment: Thank you for your response ..i have now added else clause and if the condition or not met in if clause the text box will have default value of 0..